# Executing Map of Observables

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, rx-java

Are there more elegant ways to execute and convert `Map<K, Observable<V>>` to `Map<K, V>` ?

I've found the following way:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final ImmutableMap<String, Observable<Integer>> map = ImmutableMap.of(
        "1", Observable.just(1),
        "2", Observable.just(2),
        "3", Observable.just(3)
    );

    Map<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<>(map.size());

    final Integer execRes = map.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> {
            entry.getValue().subscribe(res -> result.put(entry.getKey(), res));
            return entry.getValue();
        })
        .reduce(Observable::concat).get().toBlocking().last();

    Assert.assertTrue(execRes == 3);
    Assert.assertTrue(1 == result.get("1"));
    Assert.assertEquals("{1=1, 2=2, 3=3}", result.toString());
}
```

p.s. rxjava-1.1.7 is used and the Observable code must be run in parallel (simultaneously)

Comment: Probably a look at [`toMap`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#toMap-io.reactivex.functions.Function-io.reactivex.functions.Function-) and its overloads might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? Using Java 8 streams:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = map.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().toBlocking().first()));
```

Same using Rx:

```
Map<String, Integer> result = Observable.from(map.entrySet())
        .toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, a -> a.getValue().toBlocking().first()).toBlocking().first();
```

Comment: as I see Observables run sequentially here, it's not good, they must be executed in parallel according to used threading settings

Comment: What "threading settings"? The code you provided runs in a single thread.

Comment: you're right but I checked your code with multiple threads using `Observable...subscribeOn(Schedulers...` and it also runs sequentially. And interestingly that my code runs in parallel but the problem that it repeats Observable execution. So I think it's right to accept your answer as solution, but may be I'll create another question about parallelism for this case.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found you are using `Guava`, so we can use some convinent method in `Guava`.

And even if the value is not single, we can convert it to a `Multimap`.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.common.collect.ArrayListMultimap;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.common.collect.Maps;
import com.google.common.collect.Multimap;

import rx.Observable;

public class Q47057374 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    final ImmutableMap<String, Observable<Integer>> map = ImmutableMap.of(
        "1", Observable.just(1),
        "2", Observable.just(2),
        "3", Observable.just(3));
    System.out.println(toMap(map));
    final ImmutableMap<String, Observable<Integer>> multimap = ImmutableMap.of(
        "1", Observable.just(1, 2, 3),
        "2", Observable.just(4, 5, 6),
        "3", Observable.just(7, 8, 9));
    System.out.println(toMutimap(multimap));
  }

  public static <K, V> Map<K, V> toMap(Map<K, Observable<V>> map) {
    return Maps.transformValues(map, o -> o.toSingle().toBlocking().value());
  }

  public static <K, V> Multimap<K, V> toMutimap(Map<K, Observable<V>> map) {
    ArrayListMultimap<K, V> multimap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
    map.forEach((k, vo) -> vo.forEach(v -> multimap.put(k, v)));
    return multimap;
  }
}
```

And output:

```
{1=1, 2=2, 3=3}
{1=[1, 2, 3], 2=[4, 5, 6], 3=[7, 8, 9]}
```